# Login callback from WebView(Xamarin+.Net Core 5 identity)

Tags: xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, asp.net-identity

I have a .net core 5 Identity service. And it is created in MVC architecture. It contains **Login, Register, Forgot password** and **change password** views(.cshtml) and its codes.
I also created one Xamarin app.

How can I connect the xamarin app with .net core identity?

I put some code changes in xamarin forms but the response after login successful is not getting the result(token) on the Xamarin site.

"await Browser.OpenAsync(new Uri(loginUrl), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);"

Answer (score 1):

We cannot use xamarin forms in .Net Core as it [doesnt support template](https://vsf-prod.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/content/problem/583370/missing-azure-mobile-app-project-template-in-visua.html) in VS 2019.

Instead, we can use .Net Framework. To add a Xamarin Forms project to the solution, right-click the solution and go through the following steps: Add -> New project -> Search for Xamarin and choose a project according to your requirements. Give your app a name and click OK.

You can refer to this [BLOG](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-mvp-award-program-blog/implementing-signin-and-signup-with-xamarin-forms-and-asp-net/ba-p/428586)  for more information.